# Why cannot I create page using scaffold in CQ5?

Tags: aem

I create scaffold in cq5. I see it in my miscadmin by this url

```
miscadmin#/etc/scaffolding/myfirstscaffold
```

I fill fields - but page doesn't create.

How to know why?

[image]
[image]

when I click on button1 I don't see result

Comment: Logs?? Errors?? Configuration?? I think the question doesn't provide much information about the problem.

Comment: @rakhi4110 What information can I provide else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given info, the only issues which i can guess of is,

1. The template cannot be used under the configured path.(Check for the **allowedPaths** property and see if it is ok to use with your configured path).
2. The **name** property for your textarea i.e., "It's my jcr:content" field. Make sure you specify the name as a relative path from the page node.

i.e., in case you want to store it as a property called "foo" in "jcr:content" then provide the name as "./jcr:content/foo" and not as "./foo"(which is how we generally provide the value for the property "name" for widgets in  the components dialog). Else ConstraintViolationException may be thrown.

Even you find that the issue is still there, then check the network tab in devtools(F12) and provide the response for the POST request to /content/home/en/*

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem could be with the target template you have chosen.
Try debugging by pressing F12 and look for any error during the sling Post operation when u hit create.

Comment: @Sriramu sing with template I can create pages